# Редиркт на конкретную страницу

Tags: .htaccess

Нужно сделать редирект со старой версии страницы `/categories?id=4` на новую `/category/scripts` . Двумя способами пробовал и не получается:

```
RewriteRule  ^categories?id=4/$ /category/scripts [R=301,L]
Redirect 301 /categories?id=4 /category/scripts
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверка параметра делается отдельно. Тут точное совпадение проверяется с `id=4` (других параметров в строке запроса не должно быть).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/categories
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=4$
RewriteRule .* /category/scripts? [L,R=301]
```